# how to merge individual words into one line

Tags: python, list, words

I've done the following:

1. opened file
2. split into list
3. made reverse loop by using `for` loop
4. output like below :

`# I am interested in position Dualer Master (w/m) im Bereich "Next Generation B2B`

```
B2B
Generation
"Next
Bereich
im
(w/m)
Master
Dualer
position
in
interested
am
I
```

Now I need to remerge these individual words again into one line, any help?

Below is my code:

```
fh = open('new.txt', 'r')
for file in fh :
    line = file.split()
    for word in reversed(line):
        print(word)
```

Comment: You can use the `join` method to join a list of strings up into one big string. For example, after `columns = row.split(',')` (and maybe editing the columns), you can do `row = ','.join(columns)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `sep` and `end` arguments to `print` to print a bunch of values on the same line without `join`ing them up first.

Comment: But meanwhile, what are all these tags there for? For example, are you looking for an answer in Pyth or Java instead of in Python, despite your existing code being in Python? Or are you just spamming random tags for no reason? Doing that is just going to attract Java experts who don't know Python and will downvote your question for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: sorry for that still new at site

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
Consult a tutorial that includes operations on strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can generate output like:

```
B2B
Generation
"Next
Bereich
im
(w/m)
Master
Dualer
position
in
interested
am
I
```

By formatting the `print` function you can remerge the output. Like

```
fh = open('new.txt', 'r')
for file in fh :
    line = file.split()
    for word in reversed(line):
        print(word, end=' ')
```

If you want this as string for reusing, you can join the words.
Full code

```
fh = open('new.txt', 'r')
oneLineString = ''
for file in fh :
    line = file.split()
    for word in reversed(line):
        print(word)
        oneLineString+= (word + " ")
print(oneLineString)
```

Output:

```
B2B
Generation
"Next
Bereich
im
(w/m)
Master
Dualer
position
in
interested
am
I
B2B Generation "Next Bereich im (w/m) Master Dualer position in interested am I
```